# Where should the condition variables, mutexes be declared when the threads deal with different classes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Here I have declared everything globally. Where should the condition variables, mutexes be declared when they are shared between different classes?

What design should be followed so that global declaration can be avoided?

```
#include "thread_class.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

// Thread_manager class: ***************************************************************************************************************
std::queue<int> queue_m;

std::mutex mutex_k;

bool watch;

std::mutex mutex_x;
std::mutex mutex_y;

std::condition_variable cv_x;
std::condition_variable cv_y;

ThreadManager::ThreadManager() : obj_thread_B_( &B::Run, &obj_class_B_),
                                 obj_thread_A_( &A::Run, &obj_class_A_ )
{
    watch = false;
}

ThreadManager::~ThreadManager()
{
    obj_thread_A_.join();
    obj_thread_B_.join();
}

void A::Run()
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( mutex_x );
        while (watch == false)
            cv_x.wait( lk );

        std::cout << "\nA class\n";

        someint++;
        queue_m.push( someint );

        cv_y.notify_all();

        // some time consuming operation
        for (int t = 0; t < 1000000; t++)
        {
        }
    }
}

void B::Run()
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        std::cout << "\nB class\n";

        if (queue_m.size() > 0)
        {
            int temp = queue_m.front();
            std::cout << "\nTaken out: " << temp;
            queue_m.pop();

            cv_x.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( mutex_y );
            watch = true;

            cv_x.notify_all();

            cv_y.wait( lk );
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we declare condition variables, mutexes in the same class because we use both for controlling, scheduling and prioritize threads. I don't think we need to declare globally for condition and mutexes. But still if you really need that you can use a namespace here.